# Using jquery variable as an argument for an ActionLink in .net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, controller

It's just me or it is really difficult to work with variables in javascript?

My problem is that I want to use some results of my javascript function into a MVC .net Controller, and I just can't!

1.- My JavaScript function runs on a view:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#go').click(function () {
             // test for presence of geolocation
             if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error);

             } else {
                 // nothing at this moment.
```

......

```
   function geo_success(position) {
         printLatLong(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
     }
```

Besides printLatLong function, I want to use the argument position.coord.latitude to send it to a controller through Html.ActionLink like this:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Link to Controller", "Action", "Controller", position.coords.latitude)
```

But I can't use position.coords.latitude since now I'm out of the function. I just want to use that value as an argument in my ActionLink, is that too difficult?? :(

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You seem confused as to the differences between client-side and server-side code.

Comment: Not at all, I want to do some operations with the coordinates at server-side, it's just that I obtain them with client-side code. I'm supposed to make calculations client-side too? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it with html anchor and manipulate the href attribute via jquery.

Script:

```
function geo_success(position) {
    printLatLong(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var url = '@Url.Action("Geo", "Home")';
    // grab the anchor and modify the url
    $("#geolink").attr("href", url += "?latitude=" + position.coords.latitude);
}
```

In your view

```
<a id="geolink">GeoLink</a>
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Geo(int latitude)
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Do something with: {0}", latitude));
    }
```

Comment: If you want to keep the ActionLink helper, you may add the id like so: @Html.ActionLink("Link to Controller", "Action", "Controller", new { id = "geolink" })